# Include Virtual Columns in toArray() Call with PropelORM

Tags: php, orm, propel

In a PropelORM object retrieved from a query with virtual columns from a join, is there a way/method to include virtual columns in the toArray() call?

For example:

```
$book = BookQuery::create()
  ->join('Book.Author')
  ->with('Author')
  ->where('Author.Name = ?', 'Jane Austen')
  ->findOne();

$aBook = $book->toArray();
```

In the above code, I would like the array generated in the toArray() call to have the fields from the Authors table as well, not just the Books table.

Comment: it was a propel bug. it is corrected now on github

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the *toArray()* method definition, you'll see that it accepts a *$includeForeignObjects* parameter. I think it's more or less what you are looking for.

```
$book = BookQuery::create()
  ->join('Book.Author')
  ->with('Author')
  ->where('Author.Name = ?', 'Jane Austen')
  ->findOne();

$aBook = $book->toArray($keyType = BasePeer::TYPE_PHPNAME, $includeLazyLoadColumns = true, $alreadyDumpedObjects = array(), $includeForeignObjects = true);
```

The arguments list isn't pretty, but it should work.

Comment: Could you please link to the docs where it states $includeForeignObjects, for me all the docs seem to end at $alreadyDumpedObjects = array()